sklearn SVR taking LESS time for MORE samples
I am using an sklearn.svm.SVR for a time-series regression problem, cross-validating via TimeSeriesSplit:
svr = make_pipeline(
    PandasSimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value=0),
    make_column_transformer(
        (OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown="ignore"), ["categorial_column"]),
        remainder="passthrough",
        verbose_feature_names_out=False,
    ),
    SVR(),
)

svr_results = cross_validate(
    estimator=svr,
    X=X_train,
    y=y_train.values.ravel(),
    cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=9),
    scoring="neg_root_mean_squared_error",
)

I have a dataset with more than 60000 samples with 15 features. In my prior tests with round about 9000 samples and 15 features, the SVR were quite quick at the beginning but took up to 3 Minutes for the last CV. Which now I think about it is also fairly lowish I feel like.
However, this time - with the complete dataset - I stumbled over this CV output, which really confuses me, as the sample size of the training data should be consistently growing when using a TimeSeriesSplit - and therefore also the runtime of the SVR.
[CV] END .................................................... total time= 1.1min
[CV] END .................................................... total time= 1.8min
[CV] END .................................................... total time=  12.6s
[CV] END .................................................... total time=  17.7s
[CV] END .................................................... total time=  33.3s
[CV] END .................................................... total time=  50.7s
[CV] END .................................................... total time= 1.2min
[CV] END .................................................... total time= 1.3min
[CV] END .................................................... total time= 4.9min

What could be going wrong in the middle part, where the time used for that CV suddenly drops drastically?
